# No matching function (input/output)

Tags: c++, function, input, output

I am writing a program which works with input/output and I have a problem with two functions in my code: `copyText` and `print`. They don't work at all and I can't understand the source of my problem. I will really appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void initialize(int&, int[]);
void copyText (ifstream&, ofstream&, char&, int[]);
void count(char, int[]);
void print(ofstream&, int, int[]);

int main()
{
    int line;
    int letter[26];
    char ch;
    ifstream infile;
    ifstream outfile;
    infile.open("input.txt");
    outfile.open("output.txt");
    initialize(line, letter);
    infile.get(ch);
    while(infile)
    {
        copyText(infile, outfile, ch, letter);
        line++;
        infile.get(ch);
    }

    print (outfile, line, letter);
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
void initialize(int& loc, int list[])
{
    loc = 0;
    for (int i =0; i <26; i++)
        list[i] = 0;
}

void copyText(ifstream& in, ofstream& out, char& ch, int list[])
{
    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        out << ch;
        count (ch, list);
        in.get(ch);
    }
    out << ch;
}
void count(char ch, int list[])
{
    ch = toupper(ch);
    int index = static_cast<int>(ch)-static_cast<int>('A');
    if (0 <= index && index < 26)
        list[index]++;
}
void print (ofstream& out, int loc, int list[])
{
    out << endl<< endl;
    out << " The number of lines is "<<loc <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<26; i++)
        out << static_cast<char>(i+static_cast<int>('A')) << "count =  " <<list[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "They don't work at all"?

Comment: I have this: no matching function for call(for both)

Comment: Is `ifstream outfile` supposed to be `ofstream outfile`?

Comment: That's the problem: outfile is incorrectly declared as an `ifstream`. Simple typographical error.

Comment: I was trying to copy the text from input file to output file

Comment: OMG, guys, thank you:)!

Comment: It seems the program can copy input to output perfectly, but doesn't show the result of calculation properly (amount of lines and letters). Any thoughts?